# MVC - SQL Session State vs Storing values in db

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session, asp.net-mvc-2

Reading conflicting opinions on using SQL session state vs custom db table in MVC to store user data across page requests?

What are the advantages and disadvantages to each method? Why should I pick one method over the other.

So far it seems a custom db table is the best solution because it doesn't time out, plus it would be strongly typed using the Entity Framework.

Am I missing something?

Comment: May be missing impact of performance? Database access costs much more than memory access, like standard asp.net session state.

Comment: In process session state is not an option, this needs to work in a server farm scenario. Both methods in the title are SQL based for that reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like SQL session state is the way to go if you need your data to expire, otherwise a custom database table seems like the way to go. Especially when using entity framework, less work to setup and you get a strongly typed object. No Session["VarName"] stuff..

Answer (score 1):

These articles outline strategy and performance for the various methods of Session storage.

- [ASP.NET Session State FAQ](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/articles/20021016.asp)
- [Selecting the Method for Maintaining and Storing ASP.NET Session State](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc784861%28WS.10%29.aspx)
- [ASP.NET Session State: Architectural and Performance Considerations](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tims/archive/2003/11/21/57453.aspx)
- [ASP.NET Cache and Session State Storage](http://west-wind.com/Weblog/posts/1214.aspx)

Comment: I understand how session state works and all the different methods. I have used it plenty is ASP.NET forms. What I'm trying to figure out is why would I use SQL session state, instead of just creating a custom table to store data in the db.